# Conversion error on rows not included when merge join is used

Tags: sql-server

I've run into a conversion error on a value from a row that should have been filtered out by a condition on a joined table, when MERGE JOIN is used.

Here is a small example:

```
declare @Types as table (
    [Id] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Type] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL)
insert @Types values
(1, 'Time'),
(2, 'Number')

declare @Values as table (
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LogDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL)
insert @Values values
(1, '2018-03-01', '07:03:04'),
(2, '2018-03-01', '565')

select [Values].LogDate, [Types].[Type], convert(int, [Value]) as [Value]
from @Types [Types] 
inner MERGE JOIN @Values [Values]
  on [Values].TypeId=[Types].Id 
  where [Type] = 'Number'
```

The query is supposed to only use the rows in @Values that are marked with TypeId=2, that is, 'Number's. But running it gives this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '07:03:04' to data type int.
```

If the join hint is changed to use LOOP or HASH join the query works without error, giving the expected result:

```
LogDate    Type       Value
---------- ---------- -----------
2018-03-01 Number     565
```

Another workaround is to use try_convert() instead of convert()

But, is this really something that could be expected when a MERGE JOIN is used? Normally you can assume that the calculations in the select list are only performed on the rows that are queried, right? Or will the query optimizer normally avoid merge joins when this can be a problem?

Comment: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). Do you want the bad news? Raised in 2010 and despite MS occasionally commenting that they might look into it for the "next" version of SQL Server, no indications that it'll actually happen.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the link! Then at least I have something to tell the customer.